# Connecting Transmission through OpenVPN - Docker Containers

Tags: docker, nginx, openvpn, synology, transmission

Synology DSM Version : DSM 6.2-23739 Update 2
Docker Version : Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 9f07f0e-synology

Good Afternoon,

I have been attempting to connect Transmission via a VPN using an amalgam of the information contained within :

- https://github.com/dperson/openvpn-client, and
- https://github.com/dperson/transmission

Which resulted in the following:

```
cat /volume1/docker/Open-VPN-VYPRVPN/ca.vyprvpn.com.crt  | sudo docker run -it --cap-add=NET_ADMIN \
--dns 8.8.4.4 --dns 8.8.8.8 --restart=always \
-e TZ=Australia/Brisbane \
--device /dev/net/tun --name vpn -d dperson/openvpn-client \
-r 192.168.0.1/24 \
-v "us1.vpn.goldenfrog.com;$vpnuser;$vpnpass" tee /vpn/vpn-ca.crt

sudo docker run -it --name bit --net=container:vpn \
-d dperson/transmission

sudo docker run -it --name web -p 8080:8080 -p 8443:8443 --link vpn:bit \
-d dperson/nginx -w "http://bit:9091/transmission;/transmission"
```

Starting with OpenVPN I am seeing the following error:

RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument

**Update**

I have subsequently resolved the above issue by changing 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.0.  However, now I receive the following error message in the Transmission log:

```
date    stream  content
2018-08-07 10:35:34 stdout  [2018-08-07 10:35:34.652] DHT Attempting bootstrap from dht.transmissionbt.com (tr-dht.c:249)
2018-08-07 10:34:37 stdout  [2018-08-07 10:34:37.652] transmission-daemon requiring authentication (daemon.c:554)
2018-08-07 10:34:37 stdout  [2018-08-07 10:34:37.652] Saved "/var/lib/transmission-daemon/info/settings.json" (variant.c:1266)
2018-08-07 10:34:37 stdout  [2018-08-07 10:34:37.652] Using settings from "/var/lib/transmission-daemon/info" (daemon.c:528)
2018-08-07 10:34:37 stdout  [2018-08-07 10:34:37.652] DHT Generating new id (tr-dht.c:311)
2018-08-07 10:34:37 stdout  [2018-08-07 10:34:37.652] UDP Please add the line "net.core.wmem_max = 1048576" to /etc/sysctl.conf (tr-udp.c:100)
2018-08-07 10:34:37 stdout  [2018-08-07 10:34:37.652] UDP Failed to set send buffer: requested 1048576, got 425984 (tr-udp.c:95)
2018-08-07 10:34:37 stdout  [2018-08-07 10:34:37.652] UDP Please add the line "net.core.rmem_max = 4194304" to /etc/sysctl.conf (tr-udp.c:89)
2018-08-07 10:34:37 stdout  [2018-08-07 10:34:37.652] UDP Failed to set receive buffer: requested 4194304, got 425984 (tr-udp.c:84)
2018-08-07 10:34:37 stdout  [2018-08-07 10:34:37.652] Port Forwarding Stopped (port-forwarding.c:180)
2018-08-07 10:34:37 stdout  [2018-08-07 10:34:37.652] RPC Server Password required (rpc-server.c:1117)
2018-08-07 10:34:37 stdout  [2018-08-07 10:34:37.652] RPC Server Whitelist enabled (rpc-server.c:1114)
2018-08-07 10:34:37 stdout  [2018-08-07 10:34:37.652] RPC Server Serving RPC and Web requests on port 127.0.0.1:9091/transmission/ (rpc-server.c:1110)
2018-08-07 10:34:37 stdout  [2018-08-07 10:34:37.652] RPC Server Adding address to whitelist: * (rpc-server.c:903)
2018-08-07 10:34:37 stdout  [2018-08-07 10:34:37.652] Transmission 2.92 (14714) started (session.c:738)
2018-08-07 10:34:37 stdout  [2018-08-07 10:34:37.652] Blocklist "bt_level1.bin" updated with 0 entries (blocklist.c:408)
2018-08-07 10:34:36 stdout  gzip: invalid magic
```

Obviously, it is necessary to modify the /etc/sysctl.conf, which I have done, however, when I stop the container and start it again I am presented with an error in the GUI stating "Container must join at least one network".

Any advice on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Scott

Comment: This question might be off topic. You will have more luck asking this question on the ServerFault or SuperUser StackExchange sites.